# How to deal with a large number of pages in Angular 2?

Tags: bash, angular

I'm new to Angular 2+.

I want to create an application with 121 html pages (actually an ionic3 stories application, one story is on one html template).

In this case, I must use CLI to `ng generate` 121 components or could I have another way to do this faster?

Please help me.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well you have to as the names of your components will change for each component,.Want to do it as story 1,story 2? write a bash script for the same ..might ease your work

Comment: Are the pages like enough that you could just build one page and then data bind them for 121 different types of data?

Comment: @DeborahK I thought like yours. Just one page is enough to do this. But I don't know how to do it. My template contain angular syntax and angular components too, not just only text.

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to say without seeing your templates. But if you sure need to run generate component command many times, you can do for ex: `n=1; while [[ $n -lt 3 ]]; do ng g c component${n}; n=$((n+1)); done`

Comment: To be honest, i don't want to use CLI to finish this project, I want to find a best convinent way to finish this project, like using For or While loop to easily create components?